# Set minDate to a dynamical date in jQuery datapicker

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

The minimum date setting (minDate) in a jQuery-UI datepicker should be set to the birthdate (birthdateDMY in my code). I was thinking of using an anonymous function inside .datepicker({}) but I do not know how to make it work.

```
//birthdateDMY will be something like [ "01", "07", "2015" ]
var name = jQuery("#dropdown").val();
var index = baby.Name.indexOf(name);
var birthdateDMY = baby.BirthDate[index].split("/");

jQuery(function() {   
    jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
        //need an anonymous function here to set minDate?
        minDate: (new Date(birthdateDMY[2], birthdateDMY[1] - 1,
birthdateDMY[0])),
    maxDate: 0, 
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
});
```

SOLVED USING A SETTER:

```
//Setter: update minDate for e.g. #datepicker
function updateMinDate(selector){
    //birthdateDMY will be something like [ "01", "07", "2015" ]
    var name = jQuery("#dropdown").val();
    var index = baby.Name.indexOf(name);
    var birthdateDMY = baby.BirthDate[index].split("/");
    //Update minDate in the selected item
    $(selector).datepicker("option", "minDate", new Date(birthdateDMY[2], birthdateDMY[1] - 1, birthdateDMY[0]) );
}

//When changin #dropdown, call updateMinDate
jQuery(document).on('change', '#dropdown', function(e) {
    updateMinDate("#datepicker");
}



jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate: <some code run when page loads>,
    maxDate: 0, numberOfMonths: 2, dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
  });
});
```

Comment: Maybe you could set a validation function to the date picker field, so it will not allow the user to submit the form while de date does not meet the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reinitialize your datepicker whenever your drop down changes. Right now when your page loads it sets up the datepicker and then it never changes it.
So, an event like this should help:

```
$("#dropdown").change(function(){
//reinitialize date-picker here
});
```

You might have to play around with  it a little but I think this will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes I noticed that, as I wrote it, the minDate could not change. I will try to put a getter there where I change the dropdown. 
Do you think I cannot use an anonymous function in this case, and why? Thank you!

Comment: Solved using a setter: